# Date regex validator for the following format "MMM d, y HH:mm"

Tags: javascript, regex

can you help me create a regex validator for dates in the following format: `MMM d, y HH:mm`

example: `Aug 7, 2015 00:00`
I have started with this: `^Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec`
but have no idea how to continue (regex is new for me)

Comment: Do you want very strict checks for the date and time? like say date `45` must be rejected?

Comment: yes, it should be strict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use square brackets to represent a range between two characters.

To get dates between 1 and 9 use [1-9].

To get dates between 10 and 29 use [1-2][0-9].

To get dates between 30 and 31 use 3[0-1].

Combined you get [1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1].
Which can be reduced to [1-2]?[0-9]|3[0-1].
Also [0-9] is the same as \d which means any digit. So it can be further reduced to [1-2]?\d|3[0-1].

For years above 1900 you can use 19\d\d and between 2000 and 2199 use 2[0-1]\d\d.

You get the point. In the end you should end up with something like:

```
var r = /^(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s+([1-2]?\d|3[01]),\s+(19\d\d|2[0-1]\d\d)\s+([0-1]?\d|2[0-4]):([0-5]?\d|60)$/

r.test('Aug 7, 2015 00:00'); // true
'Aug 7, 2015 00:00'.split(r); // ["", "Aug", "7", "2015", "00", "00", ""]
```

After you have the segments of the date in strings validate each one based on rules you may have.